# Kivy - How resize button on "x" in BoxLayout?

Tags: button, kivy, resize, boxlayout

I try to resize a button at the half of the width of the BoxLayout, but i don't know why that don't work on the 'x' axis.
Here my .kv file:

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,0,0,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            text: "+"
            color: 0,0,0
            size_hint: .5, .5   << HERE
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .5}
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (1,0,1,1)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
```

and what i got:

[image]

How can I resolve tis issue?

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To have your button half the width/height of the `BoxLayout` you can set the `size_hint` to `None, None`, then set the `width` and `height` with the parent settings divided by 2. See example below:

```
Button:
    text: "+"
    color: 0,0,0
    size_hint: None, None
    width: self.parent.width/2
    height: self.parent.height/2
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,0,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

I also changed the `BoxLayout` to a `FloatLayout` so that the `pos_hint` can work properly.

Hope this helps!